# how to set a profile picture for a user from her list of uploaded pictures in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

i have a model **User.rb** which allows me to set a profile picture when a user is signing up,  and another model **Upload.rb**, this upload model is for pictures uploaded by the user from his or her local machine i.e *computer*.
my question is, how do i change the profile picture for the user from one of the uploaded pictures in my database?

THANKS.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Are you trying to display the user's profile picture? Do you want the user to be able to overwrite his/her profile picture by uploading a new one? Please post some code that shows how you're doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Paperclip. Carrierwave has a `remote_file_url` helper built in, which could be useful in your case.

You could build your own in your User model:

```
def picture_from_url(url)
  self.picture = open(url)
end
```

Then you would need to construct a User form with a `:picture_from_url` field, and find some way of selecting an image from the Upload model, and passing `Upload.file_url` to the `picture_from_url` field.

Not sure specifically what you asking. Does this help?